# Css/ JS not working on IE on Web Server, works locally

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a page using Boot Strap and several other scripts and styles.

It worked fine in all browsers but IE (Surprise surprise) so after some Googling I included this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <script src="~/Scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

to my _Layout Page. This fixed the problem locally so I published the project to the dev server.

Unfortunately the styles and scripts aren't all loading on IE and I'm not sure why.

I am using bundling and have the following in my Bundle Config:

```
bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dynamic.unobtrusive.validation.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.js",
                    "~/Scripts/typeahead.bundle.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo.all.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-tagsinput.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/2014.2.903/kendo.common.min.css",
            "~/Content/site.css",
            "~/Content/widgets.css"));
```

Then in the layout I reference a few scripts outside of the bundle:

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2014.2.903/kendo.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/popcorn-complete.js"></script>
```

I then reference theo ther bundles

but none of these are loading in IE9. When I use Compatibility mode IE8 using the developer tools it is better but the Javascript files are loading.

When I use IE Dev tools It shows 4 css files, the ones I load manually and then the bundle but it doesnt contain ALL of the styles in there. I did a search for a few random classes I know to be in the stylesheets and they aren't in there.

I am assuming this is something to doing with it working locally in debug mode and not working on the server because it isn't and that this has nothing to doing with the respond.js but I cannot figure out a solution.

Anyone able to help me?

Comment: Your urls should either be relative to the webserver directory, or absolute with the full external URLs. It looks like you're referencing relatively to your local files, and the paths are different on your web server.

Comment: This relative paths `~/` means *Home directory*. It's possible that your home directory in server is in another location. Try to find how you are inserting it and what's the absolute path you are calling. Otherwise, it's better if you develop in a localhost webserver, reproducing all conditions you have in external webserver. It's good too if you show us your CSS and why it doesn't run in IE.

Comment: i dont think `~/` is a valid path

Comment: What is the source for the stylesheet links?   Has the url been resolved properly or does it still have the tilda on it?

Comment: Also I think modernizr includes html5shiv so you shouldn't need to include it sepreately - http://modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie

Comment: The file locations are the same locally and on the server. Only the virtual directory has changed. It also works on other browsers fine so I dont think it is the file paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-case anyone else has this problem this is what I did to resolve the issue.

I re-downloaded respond.js which improved it.

I also had to split out the bundle.config css in to individual items because I learned IE9 can only read so many items in a bundle and it disregards the rest.

After I did these two things it started working.